# Как отправить сообщения всем подключенным пользователям java netty

Tags: java, netty

Есть сервер на netty, при попытке отправить какое-то сообщение с сервера оно доставляется только одному пользователю(который отправил запрос). Что можно сделать чтобы сообщения с сервера доставлялись всем юзерам? Вроде читал что для начала нужно как-то получить список подключений , но это я тоже не знаю как сделать